# Find single line strings in MultiLineStrings

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have a layer of line geometries in QGIS (version 2/Dufour) and want them all to be singlepart linestrings. However, some of them are multipart geometries (MultiLineStrings in a GeoJSON export). The MultiLineStrings sometimes have small gaps, but not always. Sometimes the geometry end points are in the same position.

How can I highlight/select the individual geometries so that I can easily find the gaps?

Once I can see where the gaps are I'd like to treat them manually, e.g. close the gap manually and merge the geometries.

Answer (score 4):

OK, found a useful plugin:

[Multipart Split](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/multipartsplit)

using the Topology Checker extension, I can now find (highlight) my unwanted multipart geometries, select them by click and then use the Multipart Split plugin to split them. This allows to select the linestring geometries individually.